# Making Discord Bot - Syntax Error When Trying to Start

Tags: javascript

I am relatively new to coding so I followed a simple tutorial on how to create a Discord bot, but when I try to start it by using the command `node bot.js` in Command Prompt, I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at new Script (vm.js:73:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:245:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:297:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:266:19)
```

Can someone please help me prevent this error from occurring?

Comment: You're going need to provide your code/script/etc.

Comment: Oftentimes in order to help you we need more context like code, node version, OS and etc.